# Unobserved TOmniTask... Task controller needs an owner?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2007, omnithreadlibrary

I have written a program in Delphi 2007 using the OmniThreadLibrary. I found that the program was growing bigger and bigger in memory as it ran using the following structure to launch tasks.

```
class procedure saveIniFile(const iniFile: TStringList);
    var
        task  : IOmniTaskControl;
     begin
        task := CreateTask(saveIniFileTask, 'saveIniFile')
                   .SetParameter('iniFile', iniFile)
                   .Unobserved
                   .Schedule;
     end;
```

After reading a few blogs and looking through docs, I found that I needed to store an instance of the task in a persistent variable. Ie...

```
var
    task  : IOmniTaskControl;

class procedure saveIniFile(const iniFile: TStringList);

     begin
        task := CreateTask(saveIniFileTask, 'saveIniFile')
                   .SetParameter('iniFile', iniFile)
                   .Unobserved
                   .Schedule;
     end;
```

My question is, should this be a separate persistent variable for each instance of the task?

For example: if I launched the same task from within a loop, would each previous instance would be overwritten by the new and therefore would I need an array of instances?

The examples I have seen seem to use a single variable for all instances created but this seem wrong.

Can anyone shed any light?

Thanks

Comment: You've read this http://www.thedelphigeek.com/2009/11/omnithreadlibrary-patterns-task.html I presume

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - Yes, I think that OmniThreadLibrary is great but the docs are a bit confusing. I used .Unobserved but the threads didn't seem to free up resources so the app was growing in memory and slowing down.

Comment: How are the tasks going to be released? You appear to be asking for them not to be? Why did you want them to be unobserved?

Comment: This is where I'm getting confused... If they are Unobserved, should I just create a task and not store the instance (global or local)? If I do store the instance (which would be handy to do some other clean up tasks), does each call to CreateTask be stored in a separate persistent variable?

Comment: You need to take an explicit and conscious decision on how to clean up these tasks. The document I linked to has various examples.